# My new theme in not translating its header and footer in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed a theme in my Magento 1.9. The store has four languages including Dutch and English. But the header and footer and the themes default slider part of all pages in all languages are showing only in Dutch. The content part is translating fine. How can I correct this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento Some static content not changed auto so you need to transalate it manually by creating translate file. I give example of France Language.

1) In your theme folder/locale/fr_FR/translate.csv

2) Open this csv file and write as below formate

```
"Inspiration","Your France Translation"
```

3) Flush your cache and Just run your France Site it will Display This Translation.

[For more see here.](http://t.omlinson.com/how-to-translate-a-magento-theme/)

Comment: Thank you. Tried your method. But still it doesn't work.

Comment: Have you visited given link

Comment: Yes. And its all set up as mentioned there